# What code is executed when I call a RequestMapped class (not a method)?

Tags: java, spring

I got this calling a class defined with RequestMapping but I don't know what code is executed on the class.

```
<form th:action="@{/admin/gestionUtilisateurs.action}" method="post">
    <label>Numéro de contrat: </label>
    <input type="text" id="numeroContrat" name="numeroContrat" />
    <input type="submit" id="changerInformations" name="changerInformations" value="Charger les informations" class="w_actionButton"/>
</form>
```

And I got this class:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/admin/gestionUtilisateurs")
public class GestionUtilisateursController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, params = { "changerInformations" }, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public String getInformationContrat(HttpServletRequest request, InformationContratForm informationContrat, BindingResult result, Model model) {
        //code
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value = "/modifierMail", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseDTO> modifierMail(HttpServletRequest request, @Valid InformationContratForm informationContratForm,
        BindingResult result) {
        //code
    }

    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, params = { "importerProfilForm" }, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public ResponseEntity<ResponseDTO> importerProfilDeGestion(HttpServletRequest request, @Valid ImporterProfilForm importerProfilForm,
        BindingResult result) throws UtilisateurInexistantException {
        //code
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String processRechercheContrats(Model model) {
        //code
    }
}
```

So, I would like to know what code is executed and why.

Comment: you cannot call a class...

Comment: But the code is working.

Comment: again. you cannot call the class. There's **no code** in your class you posted (unless `// code` is a placeholder), but what is working here is most likely generated code based on your annotations.

Comment: I removed the code. There is code running on this class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the code:

```
<form th:action="@{/admin/gestionUtilisateurs}" method="post">
    <label>Numéro de contrat: </label>
    <input type="text" id="numeroContrat" name="numeroContrat" />
    <input type="submit" id="changerInformations" name="changerInformations" value="Charger les informations" class="w_actionButton"/>
</form>
```

The method getInformationContrat will be executed:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, params = { "changerInformations" }, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public String getInformationContrat(HttpServletRequest request, InformationContratForm informationContrat, BindingResult result, Model model) {
    //code
}
```

Because the input's attribute name is **changerInformations**, so it will bind with attribute params of @RequestMapping annotation.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for.